# How to use an array with russian letters?

Tags: arrays, c, string, char, c-strings

I am trying to write a code that returns how many russian vowels are input on a line. However I always get this error in the compiler "narrowing conversion of '53429' from 'int' to 'char' inside { }". I am open to any suggestinon or idea. Thanks

My idea was to make a array(glasnii) of characters and use a loop to check with every character of an input line(stroka).

```
int main (){
 char stroka[100];
 char glasnii[20] = {'А', 'Е' ,'И' ,'Ю','Ё','Ы','У','Э','О','Я','а','у', 'о', 'ы', 'и', 'э', 'я', 'ю', 'ё','е' }

 
 printf( "Введите строку : ");
 gets( stroka);
 size_t len = strlen(stroka);
 
 int count=0;
 
 for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
     for(int j=0; j<20; j++){
         if(stroka[i] == glasnii[j])
             count++;
     }
 }
 printf("\n Количество гласных : %i \n", count);
    
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is an encoding problem: each cyrillic letter is represented by more than one byte, which means it does not fit in a char. This program will most probably compile and work correctly if you look for english vowels only. Encoding problems are hard to deal with.

Comment: You may need to move to [wprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/wprintf), `wcslen` and `wchar_t` for multibyte encodings.

Comment: Your system is probably using utf-8 encoding [non-winX systems]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cyrillic chars are enooded in UTF-8 and are multibyte sequences. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Thus, doing (e.g.):

```
char vowel = 'ы';
```

Doesn't work too well because the constant in question is a sequence of *multiple* bytes. The compiler will complain that this can *not* fit in a single `char`. That's because it's actually (ignoring endianness):

```
char vowel = '\xD1\x8B';
```

We want to use `char` sequences (i.e. strings) instead.

We have to examine the upper two bits of a given `char` to determine if we're in a multibyte sequence or code point.

There are [certainly] libraries to handle UTF-8.

But if you'd like to roll your own, I've refactored your program to work with UTF-8. I've done some cursory testing for some simple sequences and it seems to work [but no guarantees]. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

typedef unsigned int code_t;            // utf8/unicode "code point"

// NOTE/BUG: the compiler flags these as multibyte constants [that can _not_
// fit in a char
#if 0
    char glasnii[20] = {
        'А', 'Е', 'И', 'Ю', 'Ё', 'Ы', 'У', 'Э', 'О', 'Я', 'а', 'у', 'о',
        'ы', 'и', 'э', 'я', 'ю', 'ё', 'е'
    }
#else
// NOTE/FIX: the compiler concatenates adjacent strings into a single string
char glasnii[] = {
    "А" "Е" "И" "Ю" "Ё" "Ы" "У" "Э" "О" "Я" "а" "у" "о"
    "ы" "и" "э" "я" "ю" "ё" "е"
};
#endif

// utf8get -- get next code point
// RETURNS: next code point (or 0) and updates the buffer pointer
//
// NOTE: this may not be a true unicode code point -- it's just the multibyte
// sequence in a single unsigned int
code_t
utf8get(char **buf)
{
    char *cp;
    unsigned char chr;
    code_t ret = 0;

    // get string pointer
    cp = *buf;

    dbgprt("utf8get: ENTER cp=%p\n",cp);

    // get first byte
    chr = *cp;

    while (1) {
        // end of string
        if (chr == 0)
            break;

        // advance pointer
        ++cp;

        // add into code point
        ret <<= 8;
        ret |= chr;

        // ordinary ascii
        if ((chr & 0x80) == 0)
            break;

        // peek at next char
        chr = *cp;

        // ordinary ascii (or EOS) -- this is a new code point
        if ((chr & 0x80) == 0)
            break;

        // start of new code point
        if ((chr & 0x40) != 0)
            break;
    }

    dbgprt("utf8get: EXIT ret=%8.8X len=%zu cp=%p\n",
        ret,(size_t) (cp - *buf),cp);

    // return updated pointer to caller
    *buf = cp;

    return ret;
}

int
countvowels(char *str)
{
    int count = 0;

    while (1) {
        dbgprt("countvowels: GETCUR\n");
        code_t curchr = utf8get(&str);
        if (curchr == 0)
            break;

        char *vowelptr = glasnii;
        while (1) {
            dbgprt("countvowels: GETVOWEL\n");
            code_t vowelcur = utf8get(&vowelptr);
            if (vowelcur == 0)
                break;
            if (curchr == vowelcur)
                ++count;
        }
    }

    printf("\n Количество гласных : %i \n", count);

    return count;
}

int
main()
{
    char stroka[100];

    // show the hex values
    for (int i = 0;  glasnii[i];  ++i)
        dbgprt("glasnii[%d] = %2.2X\n",i,(unsigned char) glasnii[i]);

#if 1
    countvowels("QыBыыT");
#endif

    printf("Введите строку : ");
// NOTE/BUG: _never_ use gets -- see the man page
#if 0
    gets(stroka);
#else
    fgets(stroka,sizeof(stroka),stdin);
    stroka[strcspn(stroka,"\n")] = 0;
#endif
    printf("\n");

    countvowels(stroka);

    return 0;
}
```